# Need help setting up multiple Realms in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbcrealm

I'm trying to set up two Realms in tomcat and it isn't letting me for some reason.  I'd like to use the standard UserDatabaseRealm (conf/tomcat-users.xml) for doing admin things (like deploying webapps) but I'd like a custom realm for doing authentication for a specific webapp.

So, I tried putting this in the context of my webapp:

```
<Context>
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="CustomDatabase" auth="Container"
      type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
      description="User database that can be updated and saved"
      factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
      pathname="/usr/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/conf/tomcat-users.xml" 
    />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" 
    resourceName="CustomDatabase"
   />
</Context>
```

Which is really just a copy of what is in server.xml with a couple changes:

- The name is changed to CustomDatabase from UserDatabase.
- The pathname is the absolute pathname (and the same I use for the main realm).

I always get this same error:

```
LifecycleException:  No UserDatabase component found under key CustomDatabase
```

And I don't know what it is telling me.  What component is it talking about?

Along with the context above I've tried a couple other things, but it always gives the same error:

- I've tried wrapping the Resource with the GlobalNamingResources tag and whether there or not same error.
- I've tried changing the auth attribute of the Resource to both Container and Application and get the same error.

What am I missing?  All the help from google is mostly people messing up their main realm (which mine is fine) not trying to configure a second realm.

Answer (score 12):

You may use `org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm`. From the Tomcat [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html):

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm" >
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
         resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
         dataSourceName="jdbc/authority"
         userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"
         userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name"/>
</Realm>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I don't have a real answer, but I'll explain what I did.

I wasn't able to get the second UserDatabaseRealm working, but I really just needed two realms for testing, and it didn't matter the type (eventually, the second realm would be LDAP).

So I was looking at the available realms and chose a MemoryRealm for my secondary test realm and it worked just as it should have.  I then made it a LDAP realm and that also worked fine.

So, sorry to those that actually need two UserDatabaseRealms, I don't have a solution for you.

NOTE: It's strange that the UserDatabaseRealm uses JNDI and the JNDIRealm is used for LDAP (and from what I can tell, JDNI isn't involved).  I'm sure this is just some legacy naming problem, but it's confusing.